# To output 1 on 1 relationship, using Python 2.76

Tags: python, dictionary

using Python 2.76, I want outputs like:

jan is 01
feb is 02
mar is 03

so I write like below:

```
Dict = {'jan':'01', 'feb':'02', 'mar':'03'}

for month in Dict.keys():
    for num in Dict.values():
        print month + " is: " + num
```

however the output is not what I wanted. Shall I use dictionary in this case, or I heading a wrong direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it output? How is the output different to what you expect?

Comment: it gives different pairings mixing with each other keys and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more straightforwardly using the `iteritems()` method on a dictionary:

```
for month, num in Dict.iteritems():
    print month, "is", num
```

What you're doing is printing each value for each key, leading to nine outputs.

Comment: thanks, Makoto. btw, why the output is not in "jan feb mar" sequence but "jan mar feb"?

Comment: Because dictionaries do not guarantee order.

Comment: @MarkK Use an `OrderedDict` if you want the keys to remain in the order you add them to the object.